# What type of script is written in BSF preprocessor..?

Tags: jmeter

I have got some jmeter scripts which have used BSF preprocessor. I don't what type of programming it is.

sample code:

```
Random=Parameters;
var DayOfLogs ="";
if (Random == 1)
{
    DayOfLogs = "019A01A601B2016D012B0144011F0120011E013A0121013F0133004E0186019D018201750196019D019501AD01BD018701660198017B0195019B01AA01B201D101C501CB01BB018F01BC020802410232020001C901B001C701AA019501CA01DE01E601C701AB01A301500156015001A401B001AF0192018D019B01480170015901CC01A1017B0196018C016501340145013A01A301B20213020801D601F201B0019101C301DC01F1020702A20328029D027B02AC02C702C202B502D002D802C702B20278028C02DA02EB0308031402D902DC02D30285028C027B02A502CF02D402DE028902680225023B0245027C01CF01BC019401A901C00196016A01C0020701FE02070202021001FC01F001A701BE01F6022201EC020301DA01F301C901A5018F01D401D401D301CC01EA01E2020301DD01B401B001D301E90214020E0273026F01D2019E0189019401C501F5018701E101CE01C701D90181016E01BA01B601C701CA01B901D201C801D301F501AC019D0210028401D101B20209028301F70207020B01EE01C701D901930177019A018601990187019F01C001C801CE017A019001860191019A0193019C01770172019601BB01AD0190018301C501A001AA0199019901A1019701BF01DA01B901C601BD01BD01B601BB0142017701BE01B8019801BC01BB01AD01E10252020501970171018D017401A8019101AA01DE0214020401E40214021D01D9021C023C022A020D01FF01B80208020601E501B501AE01E201DA01B80168017C0195019501970197018A017B0177018C0163015B0195";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Out of box JMeter provides the following scripting languages for BSF:

- JavaScript via [Mozilla Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino)
- Beanshell via [Beanshell](http://www.beanshell.org/)

Given `var` [statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) it looks like JavaScript is being used.

By the way, the language needs to be selected in the "Language" dropdown, otherwise BSF PreProcessor will fail with the "unsupported language" exception, take a look there.

[image: BSF PreProcessor]

In general it is recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements (sampler, pre/post processors, assertion, timer) for any JMeter scripting as other languages have known performance problems and can ruin your test in case of more or less severe load. See [JSR223 Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) section of [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#best_practices) for explanation and [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](https://blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) article for details of installation groovy scripting engine into JMeter, groovy scripting best practices and different scripting approaches benchmarks.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't what type of programming it is.

Looks like JavaScript to me.

Comment: The capitals actually make me think it would be C#. I'm thinking that we don't have enough information here to determine language based on inspection, and should base the answer on research.

Comment: Oh, yeah you can use var in C#. Been a while. Good addition, corsiKa!